# JSP cannot resolve Servlet data object by using JSTL, IntelliJ IDE

Tags: jsp, servlets, intellij-idea

i am now learning the basics of MVC based on servlet and .jsp; 
but when i tried to have a simple test, IntelliJ gave me warning on items="${}" of such:"This inspection reports possible EL problems, such as unresolved references and invalid EL locations";

i checked my servlet configuration in web.xml; checked the path of my .jsp file is in root, but it just doesn't work;

here's my code:

--TestView.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>test view</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:forEach var="templist" items = "${mystringlist}">
        ${templist} <br/>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
```

--TestServlet.java

```
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String[] list = {"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"};
    request.setAttribute("mystringlist", list);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/TestView.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

--web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.gpwz.labExcercise.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any advice? I searched a lot, but none of them can solve this issue...

Comment: You can try <c:out value="${templist} " />, though your version should also work.

Comment: It should be `<c:forEach var="templist" items = "${requestScope.mystringlist}">`

Comment: @dsp_user i think the problem is the data object from servlet cannot be recognized by .jsp, so the ${templist} here basicly has no reference, right?; i tried your way, not working, nothing displayed :(

Comment: @MdZahidRaza tried.. not working this way.. i even doubted if it is the jar file or my ide's fault? but i update all and cross checked on intellij and eclipse both, all the same..

Comment: It does seem to be an environment issue because the code is fine.

Comment: Is it possible that your jstl.jar is on your classpath but not deployed correctly. Make sure you have it in your app's WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: I checked, jstl api and jstl.jar all in lib folder, 1.2.1 version, btw, WEB-INF/lib is the eclipse project structure, and I actually also copied my test on eclipse IDE, and still the same resault. Gone completely mad now...

Comment: Have you fixed it? If yes, then how? Please share

Answer (score 0):

I meet this prooblem in other way,but i can`t fix it.

I was learning SpringMVC Hello world program,and finish copy code(the maven.pom..)then I find I can`t get the EL data.Same time SpringMVC ModelAndView has problem in the setViewName()

I put my mouse on this function, the hit is

> No view resolvers found Checks if Spring MVC View references are
>   resolved correctly._from IntelliJ IDE

I think maybe is some ModelAndView mapping mistake that i can`t let data go JSP

I also use the Google F12 want to look some thing,Nothing i find:(